# vertical scrolling with textview and list view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to create a view that will have many TextView and ListView items in it, it is for a TOS style page, and I need the entire page to be scrollable, but no matter what I do only the ListView items end up scrollable and everything else just runs off the page. I thought I could put the items in a FrameView with the scrollable behavior, but that's not working at all. When I add them in a ScrollView only the ListView items are scrollable. I could really use some help here.

Here is a minimized version of my layout that I have now...

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="test.notreal.justatext.TermsOfUseActivity">
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/tos_top_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:text="@string/tos_top"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/tos_top_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tos_top_items"
            android:text="@string/tos_top_end"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/tos_definition_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tos_top_items"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/tos_account_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tos_top_items"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
            android:text="@string/tos_account_description"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tos_account_line1_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tos_top_items"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/tos_account_line_title"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tos_top_items"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tos_account_line2_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tos_account_line_2_title"/>
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/tos_account_line_2_items"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried moving the frame layout above the relative layout, I have tried changing it to a ScrollView, I have tried removing the inner RelativeLayout and put the FrameLayout above the RelativeLayout so it was only a FrameLayout with a RelativeLayout in it, then all the TextView and ListView items, but nothing is working. Only the list views are scrollable, and the rest of the content runs off the screen and can't be seen. Is there some way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Oh, if it's needed I am filling the list views with an @array using ArrayAdapter, nothing fancy, just adding lines of text. Thank you.

Comment: I would personally remove everything and replace it with a single Listview, then inject the textviews and nested scrollviews inside your adapter

Answer (score 0):

What you need to change

1.Use NestedScrollView insted of scrollview it's a powerfull then scollview. like below

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">
//Rest of your layout

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

2. Remove FrameLayout
3. set nested scrolling false to all of your ListView like below

> android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

Comment: Would I put the NestedScrollView inside the FrameLayout, or remove the FrameLayout and just have the NestedScrollView?

Comment: First put nested scrollview top of your layout  below app header <nestedscrollview> <relativelayout>....<\nestedscollview> and remove framelayout from code as it not needed